# How to handle api data when field is undefined before button click

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api

I am fetching an Api and tried to console it, but when displaying it in render of react web app I get an error as the field is undefined. I know the api has not fetched data yet but how to display empty string instead of an undefined error.

Below is my code.

```
render() {
  if (this.props.fundInquiry.loiScreenData.response.loiFields && this.props.fundInquiry.loiScreenData.response.loiFields.fields) {
    const { a, b, c } = this.props.fundInquiry.loiScreenData.response.loiFields.fields;
  }

  return (
    <>
      <FormGroup>
        <BrLabel name="loiRulesApply" styleClass="mr-sm-2" element='LOI Rules Apply:' textSize={textSize} />
        <BrText element={hasResponse ? a.value : ''} textBold={true} styleClass={"float-right"} textSize={textSize} />
      </FormGroup>
    </>
  )
}
```

Comment: I suggest you to move your return part in `if condition` and write new return outside of `if` for loading data like `return <div>Loading...</div>`

Comment: I am not showing any loader just show empty string so I used operator in BrText

Answer (score 0):

You're already checking if a property is defined before you dereference it:

```
if (this.props.fundInquiry.loiScreenData.response.loiFields
    && this.props.fundInquiry.loiScreenData.response.loiFields.fields)
```

If properties further up that chain may also be undefined, it sounds like you just need to repeat that pattern.  For example:

```
if (this.props.fundInquiry
    && this.props.fundInquiry.loiScreenData
    && this.props.fundInquiry.loiScreenData.response
    && this.props.fundInquiry.loiScreenData.response.loiFields
    && this.props.fundInquiry.loiScreenData.response.loiFields.fields)
```

Which you can also extract to its own function if it's getting a bit unwieldy in `render()`.

Answer (score 0):

try below code. For `a && a.value` is not undefined and then printing the value.

```
render(){
        const { loiScreenData : { response } } = this.props.fundInquiry
      if(loiScreenData && response.loiFields){
         const { loiFields }  = response ;
 console.log('loiScreenData.response ', loiScreenData.response );
         const { fields : {a,b,c} } = loiFields;
              console.log('fields ', fields ); 
              console.log('fields a', a); 
        //this.props.fundInquiry.loiScreenData.response.loiFields.fields
        }

           return (
        <>
         <FormGroup><BrLabel name="loiRulesApply" styleClass="mr-sm-2" element='LOI Rules Apply:' textSize={textSize} />
                                                    <BrText element={hasResponse ? (a && a.value) : ''} textBold={true} styleClass={"float-right"} textSize={textSize} />
                                                </FormGroup>
        </>
        )
            }
```

Comment: getting same error. You might be aware untill a button is clicked I wont be getting fields value

Comment: `console.log('loiFields ', loiFields );` this console you're getting any output.

Comment: console.log('loiFields ', loiFields );  I m getting as undefined